Motorcycle relay with series diode query
I would be really grateful for some advice on the following issue. A relay failed on my motorbike (2009 BMW XCountry) and I replaced it with standard relay. I have been experiencing parasitic drain from the battery, and it is related to the side stand or neutral switch. I now realise that the original relay has a diode in series on pin 85 whereas the standard relay I fitted does not. The original relay was made by TE (Tyco) part number 4-1414992-3 (see diagram). I can’t seem to find the relay or anything similar (UK)
My query is, can I fit a diode externally to the diode in series in the wire to pin 85 and continue to use a standard relay? If so what type of diode do I need. I hope this makes sense.
Thanks in advance. Pictures are original (correct) relay and the bikes wiring diagram.


